# How to list files and file sizes of a zip archive?

Tags: zip

Suppose I have a ZIP archive `myfiles.zip`. To list the files inside the ZIP file, I could do `zip -sf myfiles.zip`, which results in:

```
Archive contains:
  files/mypic.jpg
  files/myvideo.mp4
Total 2 entries (12345678 bytes)
```

Is there a way to list these files together with their file sizes? For example:

```
Archive contains:
  files/mypic.jpg  1234
  files/myvideo.mp4  456789
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use command like:

```
unzip -lv myfiles.zip
```

Here is example output of this command:

```
# unzip -lv zz.zip
Archive:  zz.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
      94  Defl:N       79  16% 02-18-2020 08:53 7be876f8  z1
     539  Defl:N      218  60% 02-18-2020 08:54 34711128  z2
    3234  Defl:N      250  92% 02-19-2020 14:06 46aba2a1  z3
--------          -------  ---                            -------
    3867              547  86%                            3 files
```

Comment: How can I get human-readable file sizes (e.g. 1KiB, 2MiB, 3GiB, etc.)?

Comment: @Flux, I am afraid there is no such option in `unzip` this is managed automatically by the program